# how to remove leading and trailing slash in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, trim

I need to query remove / from url fields in the table menu

original table

```
menuname url
home     /home/
about    /home/about/
```

requirement

```
menuname   url
home       home
about      home/about
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT TRIM( BOTH  '/'    FROM  '/bar/' )
```

EDIT

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH  '/' FROM link ) FROM menu
```

Answer (score 17):

This is how you remove trailing slashes from a field:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name`=TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM `field_name`)
```

Comment: And to trim at the beginning, it's LEADING instead of TRAILING, cool!

Answer (score 3):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Example:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM home, about) FROM 'table_name';
```